# Can i Fill LinkedHashMap With an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My Question is can i fill `LinkedHashmap` Using `ArrayList` Elements?

Because every time it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.Below is my code,

```
 ArrayList<String> contactsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> numbersArray = new ArrayList<String>();
linkedMap = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
linked = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
int x = contactsArray.size();
if (contactsArray.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {
        linked.put("1", contactsArray.get(i));
        linked.put("2", numbersArray.get(i));
    }
    linkedMap.add(linked);
}else{
    msg("0");
}
```

Logcat:

```
 02-27 11:05:24.859: E/AndroidRuntime(3223): Caused by:
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
```

Comment: Is the size of `numbersArray` same as `contactsArray` ?

Comment: wat is the type of contactsArray and numberArray? Are they ArrayList or String array?

Comment: i got it now no it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the iteration with `contactsArray` and getting values from `numbersArray`. This is buggy. you should change your code to check the indexes on both array objects. Then, retrieve values from them. The above code will work only when both the collection have same number of values. As said by blackbelt, you need to have a condition to exit the loop when any of the collection last index is reached to avoid the exception. Another neat way is to change your `conditional test` in `for` loop like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < contactsArray.size() && i < numbersArray.size(); i++) {
```

Comment: or at least update the loop exit condition to the min of the two sizes

Comment: @blackbelt yes, agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition as follows...since you are retrieving values from tow different arrays then you have to check for both arrays.

```
int x = contactsArray.size();
int y = numbersArray.size();
if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x - 1 && i < y-1; i++) {
        linked.put("1", contactsArray.get(i));
        linked.put("2", numbersArray.get(i));
    }
    linkedMap.add(linked);
}else{
    msg("0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this one:

```
linkedMap = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
linked = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        int size = contactsArray.size();
        if (contactsArray.size() > 0 && numbersArray.size()>0) {
            int iterator = (contactsArray.size() > numbersArray.size()) ? contactsArray.size() : numbersArray.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterator ; i++) {

                linked.put("1", contactsArray.get(i));
                linked.put("2", numbersArray.get(i));

            }
            linkedMap.add(linked);
        }else
        {
            msg("0");
        }
```

You should make sure that your iterator loops on the min size of both arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0, i = 0;

        ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> linkedMap;
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> linked;

        ArrayList<String> contactsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> numbersArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        linkedMap = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
        linked = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        for (String item : contactsArray) {
            linked.put("1", item);
            if (i < numbersArray.size()) {
                linked.put("2", numbersArray.get(i));
                i = i + 1;
            }
            linkedMap.add(linked);
        }

        if (contactsArray.isEmpty()) {
            msg("0");
        }
    }
```

}